# JuiceUI implementation on a Virtual Directory in IIS

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, juice-ui

**General Description :**

I have installed JuiceUI on a local build of a web form application in asp.net in Visual Studio 2010. What I want to do is take this application and add it to a virtual directory that has been setup for me. I have JuiceUI working on my local version, but it does not load the AJAX (such as the datepicker [i.e. calendar]) on the virtual directory.

Any help to get this loaded onto the virtual directory would be very much appreciated.

**Details I know to give at the moment :**

This is a web form application. To deploy to the virtual directory, I copy and paste the directory of my code into the directory space on the server. Therefore my bin folders and jquery are loaded on my app folder. I have configured the parent website web.config membership provider so that I can connect and access my app.
So I have had my page working just fine on the virtual directory. I installed JuiceUI on my local build and was now copying it to the website to realize that none of the ajax functionality was working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the first step is to verify that the browser is loading the necessary js and css files. Use chrome inspector or firefox+firebug and look for any 404s on the resources. If the scripts and css aren't loading, then you'll need to adjust their location in code to match your setup.